# WCF WebAPI Oauth

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api2, ws-security

I've have a WCF Service which receives a user and password stored as parameter in each call. I want the WCF Service to consume a WebAPI using Oauth. The WebAPI is already developed. I don't want to let the user authenticate when a WCF call is invoked for the same user. What is the best practise for this?